# How to output a text file in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google scripts to try and output 2 .txt files by reading in the information from Sheet 1.

I want my files to look like below one for just titles and the other for footnotes:

Therefore the ‘|’ character in the footnote column needs to split onto a new line with the same program name listed as above.

The attached sheet is a basic example, but I need guidance which would also work if the footnote column had multiple ‘|’ characters.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should show your  current script and ask a specific programming question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Use the `split()` JS String method to obtain your strings in a single array.

When obtaining the values from a Spreadsheet the Apps Script methods will arrange them in multidimensional Arrays using this fashon: `sheet[rows][columns]`.

In this example I will use the 3rd column, but you can of course adapt this method to whatever column serves you best:

```
function splitter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var thirdColumnValues = ss.getDataRange().getValues().flatMap(row => row[2].split('|'));
  var text = thirdColumnValues.join("\n"); //Just concatenate the values with the "return" symbol
}
```

### Reference

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

[JS String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)